# Flutter Infinite scroll pagination not refreshing after an item list is removed

Tags: flutter

After removing an item from a pagination, I'm getting an Ranger error (index)
I want to update my paginated list as soon as an item is removed or even added, this is the code I'm using, how can I remove the item and update it without any issue.

```
PagingController<int, Content>? paginationCtrl;

paginationCtrl!.itemList!
        .removeWhere((element) => element.id == ID);
```

Comment: Could provide the full code?

Comment: I think, you need to wrap this call into setState:

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to set `paginationController.itemList` instead of modifying it in place.

Try

```
paginationCtl!.itemList! = paginationCtl!.itemList!.where((element) => element.id != ID)
```

This should trigger the `ValueNotifier` in `PagingController` and refresh the UI.

[Source Code](https://github.com/EdsonBueno/infinite_scroll_pagination/blob/master/lib/src/core/paging_controller.dart#L57)